# strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' but received a 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, datetime, strftime

I am trying to get a list of all the `TimeFrame`s that are unique in my dataset.
My dataset has a lot of measurements that according to the year that I am studying has different time measurements. For instance, in 2021 the measurements are made every 15 minutes and in 2020 It was every 20 minutes.
As I want to compare the measurement disregarding the date, caring only about the time, I am trying to get a list of the TimeFrames in the Dataset.
This is what I have so far:

```
Data['Date | Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(Data['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
Data = Data.set_index((Data['Date | Hour']))
Data['Hour']=Data.index.time
Data['Date']=Data.index.date
TimeFrames=[]
V=Data['Hour'].unique()
a=np.arange(0,len(V))
for i in a:
    TimeFrames.append(datetime.strftime(V[i],'%H:%M:%S'))
```

It should result in something like:

```
TimeFrames=['00:00:00','00:15:00','00:30:00','00:45:00' ...
```

However, it results in:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'datetime.time'
```

I tried to do it with the date (`V=Data[‘Date’].unique()`) and it worked resulting in a list of dates…
I was thinking that maybe I could just add a random date to `V`, run the for cycle and after getting the list delete the date from all the strings resulting in the list that I want but that would be my last option.. any ideas??

Comment: As a workaround, instead of strftime, you can use `str(V[i]).replace(':', '-')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `strftime` is available as a method of the classes `datetime.datetime`, `datetime.date` and `datetime.time` (see also [documentation on datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)), and you are dealing with a `datetime.time` object here.

So you should be fine by changing your last line to something like

```
time.strftime(V[i],'%H:%M:%S')
```

which calls the correct one of the three methods (of course you must import the class using `from datetime import time`).

To make it even shorter, you can iterate directly over the array (no need for `V` and `a`):

```
for v in Data['Hour'].unique():
    TimeFrames.append(time.strftime(v,'%H:%M:%S'))
```